# xcode does not show files in the commit window

Tags: xcode

I have checked out a copy of a SVN project, I have modified some files and want to commit the changes. If I go to File > Source Control > Commit. I see an empty list and a button saying "Commit X files". I expected a list of the modified files.

Now, I use the command line tool (svn ...). But I want to bring back the Xcode commit window.
How may I fix it?

BTW. I'm using Xcode 4.6.1

[image: This is what I see]

Comment: You're problem is that you're using Xcode's svn integration. Try out GitX :)

Answer (score 1):

That is a very very strange screen shot. Sometimes Xcode's svn integration can be a bit strange. If I were you I would just cancel out of the strange empty dialog and use svn at the command-line in Terminal instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the command-line in terminal. Still, looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In file > preferences there is a source control section. You probably have the check box checked to update the source control automatically. So, because it is already updating the source control, it doesn't let you do it.

So you can uncheck that box to make it not automatic, then change something in your project and try to commit the changes. You will probably see some files now.